# How to get the request header from TNetHTTPClient

Tags: delphi

How to get the request header from `TNetHTTPClient`?

I have the following code:

```pascal
var
  netC: TNetHTTPClient;
  strim: TStringStream;
  aResponse: IHTTPResponse;
begin
  netC := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try   
    strim := TStringStream.Create;
    try
      aResponse := netC.Get('https://google.com', strim);
    finally
      strim.Free;
    end;
  finally
    netC.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please clarify the issue. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want get request header with ihttprequest

Comment: but for what purpose? What are you planning on doing with it if you could obtain it?

Comment: I want to know the header I sent

Comment: halo Mr Remy Lebeau can you help me ?

Comment: I don't see anything in `T(Net)HTTPClient` that supports what you are asking for. You will likely have to use a different HTTP library that does.

Comment: ok thank you remy, but how to set http 1.2 on tnethttpclient ?

Comment: There is no HTTP 1.2.  Did you mean TLS 1.2?